# What is the "standard" size of the stack and the heap in a C program?

Tags: c, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have read that the "standard" and initial stack size on Linux is ~8MB and Windows is ~1MB.

But how does the heap allocation work? Does the OS set a "virtual" size to the process heap like it does for the stack with committed and reserved memory?

Comment: It's not only for a C program, and yes, it's totally OS dependent.

Comment: OK, I just tried to be specific. Because the JVM heap exists too.

Answer (score 3):

Classically, the layout of a program has the 'text' (or 'code') segment at the low end of memory, followed by the fixed data ('data' and 'bss' segments), followed by a gap, with the stack growing downwards from high memory.  The gap in the middle becomes the heap, which grows from the end of the data towards the stack.

Things are more complex with threaded programs, shared libraries loaded, shared memory, etc.

The initial stack size is o/s dependent.  The initial heap size is logically zero, but tends to grow almost immediately (as the program and the shared libraries are loaded).

Comment: And What is the limit of the heap size?. It would be the same as the stack? I found this file that contains the max size for the stack in some architectures [link](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt)

Comment: @user1030615 no the heap is far bigger than the stack. It's generally "what's left over" when all the other sections get their memory.

Comment: So this brings me another question, What is the size of "what's left over" I mean the size of the total memory layout.

Comment: On a 32-bit machine, the total address space is nominally 4 GB.  Out of that, you have the code, data, and stack segments - and anything left over can be used for heap.  Also, memory mapped files, shared memory segments, etc eat into your 4GB of virtual address space.  On a 64-bit machine, you have many times as much total available virtual memory, but approximately the same rules apply - the main difference being you won't run out of addressing capacity for the logical address space but may run out of physical address space (and even virtual address space).

Answer (score 2):

There is no general "standard size".  Individual operating systems will have a default size, but usually they can be altered with appropriate parameters in the program image or on the command line.

C executes in a vast range of systems from tiny microprocessors with only a few hundred bytes of available memory to gigantic processor arrays with hundreds of gigabytes.

In your larger systems (including most Windows and Linux environments) the stack and heap will be assigned to segments that can be expanded, so that physical memory for maximum sizes does not need to be pre-reserved.  Many micros, though, lack memory mapping hardware and the sizes must be pre-reserved (though sometimes the stack and heap are made to grow towards each other so that there's only one common limit).

Comment: I thought the normal size of the stack was 1 MB (for things like "normal" x86 PCs), no?

Comment: I found the 8MB standard size in this [document](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt)