# Should I reuse variables?

Tags: c

Let's say that i need a counter (I program in C), only once. Should I just reuse a variable that is no longer needed, instead of declaring a counter?

For instance:

```
int main() {
   int in;

   //code goes here

   for(in=0; in<10; in++)   //do something 
   //instead of using i, I reuse in and use it as a counter

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a new name for a new object is useful, just like in naming people.

Comment: @chux Can't we reuse the names of dead people? :)

Comment: It might make sense to use a variable named "counter" to count in several places. But it doesn't make sense to use it to store, say, a cost of a pound of apples.

Comment: @ Eugene Sh. Sure, but not as I understand it in the [SAG](https://www.sagaftra.org/content/getting-started-actor-faq)  (Is the name I want already taken?)

Comment: I'd change "in" to something meaningful and use that since the for loop is already making "in" a counter variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are coding style rules such as to restrict variables' scope and lifetime to their usage. Another one is to declare variable closest to its usage.

The most idiomatic form of the `for` loop would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    // do something
```

Using the:

```
for(in=0; in<10; in++)   // do something
```

may potentially mislead a maintenance programmer, that `in`'s value is readed *after* the scope of the `for` loop.

Comment: On embedded system with lower power and low ram (stack) you probably want to limit local variables declaration. somebody use macro to explicitly name the variables sharing.

Comment: @rom1nux: OTOH by narrowing scope of stack-placed variable , you are effectively _saving_ the memory, because space occupied by its object is released as soon as its scope ends, so a compiler may utilize it for another purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the reason you would want to do this would be for efficiency. You may think that by reusing variables, you are avoid extra unnecessary memory allocations and technically you would be right. The above code you provided would work fine however reusing declared variables to store unrelated data is generally a bad coding practice and unnecessary.

It is a bad coding practice because it makes your code more difficult to understand and maintain and this becomes doubly true when you give your code to someone else to maintain. And while you are saving some space on the stack I would argue that it isn't worth making your code unreadable. In the example you gave

```
int main() {
   int in;

   //code goes here

   for(in=0; in<10; in++)   //do something 
   //instead of using i, I reuse in and use it as a counter

   return 0;
}
```

`int in` is an integer that lives on the program stack. An integer is normally 4 bytes in a C program. And the [size of the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017499/what-is-the-standard-size-of-the-stack-and-the-heap-in-a-c-program) in a modern operating system is not really something you need to worry about for your average C program. So in exchange for making your code more difficult to maintain (both by yourself and others), the only benefit is saving 4 bytes on your programs stack. Specific development constraints may make this a good trade off in certain cases but this is rarely true and shouldn't be done unless completely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse it if you really want to but you are not saving much for a simple variables (you save same space on the stack).

For maintenance purposes all variables (as wells as functions and structures) should have a meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on variable name. When both pieces of code performs similar operation and variable name is still good, you can reuse it (as long as you make sure code is still correct). But if variable was used for completely different purpose, this will make code much harder to read. So for example this is acceptable:

```
int n;
for (n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
  do_something(n);
for (n = 5; n < 100; ++n)
  do_something_else(n * 2);
```

This usage is bad:

```
int timeout = get_timeout();
start_timer(timeout);

for (timeout = 0; timeout < 5; ++timeout)
  status[timeout] = SUCCESS;
```

The latter example should be rewritten in this way to make it more readable:

```
int timeout = get_timeout();
start_timer(timeout);

int n;
for (n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
  status[n] = SUCCESS;
```

Answer (score 0):

This depend, as always, on the performance, size and maintenance/readability of your code.
In most case you probably need maintenance and readability so you keep your code clear with explicit variable name and don't reuse them to avoid confusion. 
In time critical code and/or on low resource system you probably want to reuse a lot because you want to avoid to load the stack too much.

If your compiler is C99 compliant, you can use restrict the variable scope for their usage but be careful, your compiler may not handle this very well and continue to load the stack in some case.
In following example restrict.c stack usage for function frame is higher than reuse.c on gcc 4.8.2

*Example : restrict.c*

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a=0;
    for(int i1=0;i1<10;i1++){
        a++;
    }
    for(int i2=0;i2<10;i2++){
        a++;
    }
    for(int i3=0;i3<10;i3++){
        a++;
    }
    for(int i4=0;i4<10;i4++){
        a++;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

*Example : reuse.c*

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, a=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        a++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        a++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        a++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        a++;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

*Example : restrict.disasm*

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $64, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 64
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, 24(%rbp)
    call    __main
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $9, -8(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
    jmp .L4
.L5:
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)
.L4:
    cmpl    $9, -12(%rbp)
    jle .L5
    movl    $0, -16(%rbp)
    jmp .L6
.L7:
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -16(%rbp)
.L6:
    cmpl    $9, -16(%rbp)
    jle .L7
    movl    $0, -20(%rbp)
    jmp .L8
.L9:
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -20(%rbp)
.L8:
    cmpl    $9, -20(%rbp)
    jle .L9
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $64, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

*Example : reuse.disasm*

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $48, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, 24(%rbp)
    call    __main
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $9, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L4
.L5:
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L4:
    cmpl    $9, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L5
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L6
.L7:
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L6:
    cmpl    $9, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L7
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L8
.L9:
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L8:
    cmpl    $9, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L9
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

In fact you can mix both statement, declare general loop counter (i,j,k) that are reuse in you function and keep important meaning variable explicitly named.